# T-SQL ORDER by sequence of numerical value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have the following recordset

[image]

I need to get the result order by field cntOrder from 1 to 4, by sequence. So, in this case, I would have,

| rxDate | rowID | cntOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-25 | 4 | 1 |
| 2021-07-26 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-07-27 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-07-28 | 1 | 4 |
| 2021-07-21 | 8 | 1 |
| 2021-07-22 | 7 | 2 |

etc

I have no idea how I can manage to do that.

Here's the data

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
rxDate SMALLDATETIME,
rowID INT,
cntNom VARCHAR(15),
cntOrder INT)



 INSERT INTO #Test VALUES
   ('2021-07-28 00:00:00', 1, 'COUCHER',4),
   ('2021-07-27 00:00:00', 2, 'SOUPER',3),
   ('2021-07-26 00:00:00', 3, 'MIDI',2),
   ('2021-07-25 00:00:00', 4, 'MATIN',1),
   ('2021-07-24 00:00:00', 5, 'COUCHER',4),
   ('2021-07-23 00:00:00', 6, 'SOUPER',3),
   ('2021-07-22 00:00:00', 7, 'MIDI',2),
   ('2021-07-21 00:00:00', 8, 'MATIN',1),
   ('2021-07-20 00:00:00', 9, 'COUCHER',4),
   ('2021-07-19 00:00:00', 10, 'SOUPER',3)
```

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Your sample results are not order by `cntOrder`, so your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cycle through the values of `cntOrder`, then you can use window functions in the `ORDER BY`.  This looks like:

```
select t.*
from #test t
order by row_number() over (partition by cntOrder order by rowid),
         cntOrder;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce278bba95bd4c57ff24519be7384201) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the way you identify a sequence of `cntOrders` is by having close `rowID`s, I'd rank the `cntOrder`s over the `rowID`s, sort by that and then by the `cntOrder`s themselves:

```sql
SELECT  rxDate, rowID, cntOrder
FROM    (SELECT rxDate, rowID, cntOrder, 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cntOrder ORDER BY rowID) AS rk
         FROM   #Test) t
ORDER BY rk, cntOrder
```